# Using Django to show YouTube videos in templates

Tags: django, templates, youtube

I'm attempting to store a list of YouTube links in a model then passing it as a list to a template where it's rendered using YouTube's embed code. Everything seems to be working fine, the variables are passed properly except the videos don't show up. The YouTube iframe code is just blank whereas a copy/pasted of YouTube embed code displays just fine.

The code in the Model:

```
from django.db import models

class Video(models.Model):
    link = models.URLField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.link
```

The code in the View:

```
def index(request):
    full_list = Video.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('index.html', {'full_list': full_list})
```

The code in the Template:

```
<h1>YouTube list</h1>
{% if full_list %}
    <ul>
    {% for video in full_list %}
        <li>
<!-- link passed to embed code, this shows up as blank -->
<iframe width="560" height="345" src="{{ video.link }}?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>

<!-- YouTube embed link copy/pasted as is -->
<iframe width="560" height="345" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/vLmNvYTTWXM?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        </li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No videos available</p>
{% endif %}
```

Screenshot of the browser: https://img.skitch.com/20110910-t78bm288mxh6nmyjmcbxyjr37n.png

I'm guessing that the templates are rendered first and the variable is added second hence YouTube's server is not even called. Is this a correct assumption and if so how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code is correct as I can see.
Mb you will show us result html code?
The only thing thay may be wrong is lack of `__unicode__` method in your model.
You should use not `__str__` but `__unicode__`.

Comment: Now I feel dumb. Finally figured out the problem in the HTML code. YouTube iFrame embed changes the URI, it's different from the YouTube URL. The old embed code does the same thing. I wrote up code to regex the YouTube video ID and put that into the embed code and it works fine. Thanks for your help again!

Comment: @ Jerry Can you please paste the code what you did i need to do exactly same thing and facing the same problem also

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a template tag, which does exactly what's needed above.

https://gist.github.com/chhantyal/5396911

Answer (score 0):

You could use this library to make your life easier:

https://github.com/jazzband/django-embed-video

Embed Videos the Easiest Way:

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from embed_video.fields import EmbedVideoField

class Item(models.Model):
    video = EmbedVideoField()  # same like models.URLField()
```

**template**

```
{% load embed_video_tags %}

The video tag:
{% video item.video as my_video %}
  URL: {{ my_video.url }}
  Thumbnail: {{ my_video.thumbnail }}
  Backend: {{ my_video.backend }}

  {% video my_video "large" %}
{% endvideo %}

Or embed shortcut:
{% video my_video '800x600' %}
```